# Postgresql "ERROR: cannot specify default tablespace for partitioned relations"

Tags: postgresql

I am migrating DB from Oracle to PostgreSQL14 ,
Oracle partitioned table was being used which i am trying to migrate to PG.

Below script i am using  to create partition with index and tablespace

and getting

> ERROR: cannot specify default tablespace for partitioned relations

```
create table TABLE1
(
    COL_DT date constraint N_COL_DT not null
    ,COL_TM numeric(9) constraint N_COL_TM not null
    ,COL_INPROC_ID numeric(1) constraint N_COL_INPROC_ID not null
    ,COL_SUB_ID numeric(7) constraint N_COL_SUB_ID not null
    ,COL_RECORD_DT date constraint N_COL_RECORD_DT not null
    ,COL_RECORD_TM numeric(9) constraint N_COL_RECORD_TM not null
    ,COL_TIMEOFFSET varchar(6) constraint N_COL_TIMEOFFSET not null
    ,COL_TYPE numeric(1) constraint N_COL_TYPE not null
    ,COL4 numeric(1) DEFAULT 0 not null
    ,CONSTRAINT PK_COL primary key (COL_DT,COL_TM,COL_INPROC_ID,COL_SUB_ID) using index tablespace ${TABLESPACE_INDEX}
)   partition by range (COL_DT);


CREATE TABLE P_TABLE1_1 PARTITION OF TABLE1 FOR VALUES FROM (MINVALUE) TO (to_date('${PARTITION_DATE_LIMIT}', 'YYYYMM')) partition by list (COL_INPROC_ID);


CREATE TABLE P_TABLE1_1_P0 PARTITION OF P_TABLE1_1 FOR VALUES IN (0) ;
CREATE TABLE P_TABLE1_1_P1 PARTITION OF P_TABLE1_1 FOR VALUES IN (1) ;


CREATE TABLE PMAXVALUE PARTITION OF TABLE1 FOR VALUES FROM (to_date('${PARTITION_DATE_LIMIT}', 'YYYYMM')) TO (MAXVALUE) partition by list (COL_INPROC_ID);

CREATE TABLE PMAXVALUE_P0 PARTITION OF PMAXVALUE FOR VALUES IN (0) ;
CREATE TABLE PMAXVALUE_P1 PARTITION OF PMAXVALUE FOR VALUES IN (1) ;
```

i am unable to get why this error is coming whereas default tablespace is not used

Answer (score 3):

I ran your statements, and they work like they should, once I substituted constants for the placeholders. However, before v12 it would not have worked the way you want, see the [release note](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/release-12.html#id-1.11.6.18.5) entry:

> - Allow `CREATE TABLE`'s tablespace specification for a partitioned table to affect the tablespace of its children (David Rowley, Álvaro Herrera)

So your problem is not reproducible, but since you are migrating from Oracle, let me give you a piece of advice: don't use tablespaces. They are the bread and butter of Oracle administration, but in PostgreSQL you usually use the default tablespace. There are very few valid reasons to use tablespaces, and particularly in virtualized environments they usually don't make any sense at all. And they make administration (backup etc.) more complicated.

Comment: This advice is very useful , if you can give some pointer  in what scenarios i should   use tablespace .so in my product oracle DB is using many tablespaces for indexes and LOB but i dont think there is any reason to use tablespace for indexes or other objects

Comment: There is no reason to use tablespaces for LOBs (there are none, or rather, you don't have to deal with them directly), and you don't need a tablespace for indexes. A tablespace on a different file system might be useful as substitute for disk quota.

Comment: Since we moved all databases to SSD storage, we never used a tablespace again. That was back in 2012~2013.